# "Making sludge coffee I drank with grave affect."

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What does that mean?

Does it mean that I make coffee sludge with serious face?

Or, that I make coffee sludge to be seen as grave something?

Help!

Comment: **affect** is one's demeanor, body language, and facial expression. **grave** = solemn. **sludge** is like oily mud.  So there's comic exaggeration in this statement.  "...making coffee that was like oily mud, which I drank very solemnly." The humor seems self-deprecating.

Comment: I'm a bit suspicious about [*with grave **affect***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22with+grave+affect%22). That link is to OP's source, which is the *only* occurrence of those three words in the entire Google Books corpus. But there are 118 instances of [*with grave **effect***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22with+grave+effect%22), which seems far more credible to me.

Comment: ...all relevant definitions under **affect** in [the full OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/3321?rskey=W4rc7M&result=1#eid) are marked ***obsolete***. But in this exact context I think the only really credible alternative is **affectation** - specifically, [OED's definition 2a:](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/3331?redirectedFrom=affectation#eid)  *The artificial or studied assumption of behaviour; artificiality (of manner); putting on of airs; (also) an instance of this.*

Comment: I disagree that affect is obsolete as a literary word. That said, the sentence structure is a bit off. I made sludge coffee and drank it with grave affect. Where does the sentence come from? Affect is also an underlying emotional state. /He speaks with no affect/.

Comment: Is there a source for this quote? The structure of the sentence in general seems off (the start of it, "Making sludge coffee I drank", is awkward at best and nonsensical at worst)

Comment: Context is missing here. Please do not post without giving the "provenance".

Answer (score 2):

According to [goodreads.com](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/displacement) (which I gather is meant to help people find new reading material that suits them), here is a more inclusive quote from Emma Cline's 2016 novel, "The Girls":

> “The things I was good at had no real application: addressing
>   envelopes in bubble letters with smiling creatures on the flap. **Making
>   sludgy coffee I drank with grave affect.** Finding a certain desired
>   song playing on the radio, like a medium scanning for news of the
>   dead.”

In context, it's about adolescent behavior. What it means is:

> [One of the things I was good at was] making sludgy coffee [that] I
>   drank with grave affect.

In other words, she was good at making that coffee which she then drank with an over-serious, depressive attitude (grave "**a**ffect", not "**e**ffect").

Comment: + 1 I cannot believe how people go on and on with zero context. I am very glad you posted this which now makes it possible to come up with an explanation. Your answer is the only one with any value.

Answer (score -1):

> Making sludge coffee I drank with grave affect.

Let's get rid of that adverbial phrase, *with grave affect*. We can come back to it later - it matters - but it's not relevant to analysing the rest of the sentence.

> Making sludge coffee I drank

Well, this isn't, on the face of it, a sentence. But there's a couple of ways that it nearly is.

> Making sludge coffee, I drank

This would make the principal verb *drank*, and *making sludge coffee* an adverbial. That would mean that the speaker drank (without specifying what) while making sludge coffee. That's a valid sentence, but it's a weird one. It might work, in context. Let's look at another interpretation.

> Making sludge coffee that I drank

Now, this isn't a full sentence. It's a bare gerund phrase or participle phrase, so needs more:

> I was making sludge coffee that I drank
>   I enjoyed making sludge coffee that I drank

It could also be an answer to a question:

> "What was your favourite thing about working at Bobco?"
>   "Making sludge coffee that I drank"

(A lot of these sound weird; that's because of the removed adverbial. They would be odd things to say without that adverbial, but we'll get back to that.)

Now, this all involves inserting a *that* that just isn't there in the original. However, in a phrase like that, *that* can be implicit. You just act like it's there even though it isn't.

Now, I'm sure you're fine with *that I drank* in terms of meaning, and indeed *making coffee*. There's just the question of what *sludge coffee* is. I would tend to assume, absent any other context that this meant coffee with the consistency of *sludge*, but it does seem to have some specific uses that I don't entirely grasp, looking at Google. In any case, it means coffee with some particular characteristic that makes it appropriate to apply the label of *sludge* as an attributive noun.

So, this is about making coffee that has some characteristics of sludge, and drinking. Most likely, I'd say it's about drinking the coffee - that there's an implied *that*, rather than the coffee and the drinking being independent.

So, back to the question of *with grave affect*. People often learn, to get the spellings right, that *affect* is a verb and *effect* is a noun. However, that's not always the case. Most of the time, in everyday speech - even in formal writing - that difference is true. However, there is a verb sense of *effect* (meaning *give effect to*), and a noun sense of *affect*, which means a combination of mood, emotion, and demeanour. Thus, their mood or demeanour was grave - serious or negative - when they drank the sludge coffee they had made.

One caveat, though. *Affect* isn't used in this sense much outside of medicine and psychology. I know the odd person who uses it conversationally, but it's not usual. It is, perhaps, growing in popularity as psychology becomes something more people know about. It might be used by an author trying to show off. It's hard to be sure. However, it seems to me likely that the author used it deliberately and correctly - but that doesn't make it a common turn of phrase.

Answer (score -3):

> coffee sludge

is the stuff at the bottom of a coffee cup consisting of coffee grounds made into a muddy consistency or *sludge*

[image: here]

if one drinks this, not only does it tend to be very bitter, there can also be an associated rush from the caffeine concentration which may cause headaches, the shakes, and other

> sludge coffee may affect the drinker causing grave effects

or *grave consequences*.

Comment: I think you're getting 'affect' and 'effect' mixed up...